# How to Connect MS Teams to Chat Bot Deployed in Azure Bot Service deployment "Development" Slot i.e. NOT the Production/Default Slot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-deployment-slots

Have created a ***Development Slot*** to deploy my Bot and unit test during the development process while the ***Production/default*** Slot contains the binaries for tested live ChatBot.

- We are ***successfully*** using MS Teams Channel to connect with the ChatBot hosted in the ***Production/Default*** Deployment slot.

## Need Inputs

> > > As the ChatBot in ***Development*** slot and ***Production/default*** slot both point to the same ***MicrosoftAppId*** how can I test the ChatBot Binaries in the ***Development*** slot in MS Teams as, the ***MicrosoftAppId*** is the only reference which the MS Teams Manifest requires to connect to the Chatbot which is obviously same for both slots.

Comment: ABS will still host v3 bots.  The v3 bot code is just a .net framework, or node.js web app. You can create a new Bot Channel Registration, and point it to the hosted bot code ... regardless of sdk version 3 or 4.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, My issue is that I wasn't to test the Binaries deployed in ***Development*** slot in ***MS Teams*** i.e. keeping in mind that, the Binaries deployed in the ***Production/default*** slot is live via the same MS teams and both Slots use the same ***MicrosoftAppId ***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done *exactly* this setup, but I'm pretty sure the following would work:

1. Create a new [Bot Channels Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) in Azure - this is a resource in Azure that lets you control a bot, but it's totally unlinked from hosting - it's just a "registration" (the other option in Azure, "Azure Web Bot", is what you've used now, that gives a Bot Channel Registration **AND** an Azure Web App combined together.
2. Change your AppId and AppPassword to being Deployment Slot configuration settings. Use your current ones for Prod
3. For the Dev deployment slot configuration settings, use the App Id and App Password that are generated for you in the Bot Channels Registration you created earlier.
4. Under "Settings" in your Bot Channels Registration, copy the address from your Production version, but change the first part to match the address of your dev slot (make sure the "/api/messages" is still there.

Comment: Thanks Hilton... that solves my problem of Creating another Web Chat Channel to interact with the ChatBot in the ***Development*** Slot. Would now be trying it with MS Teams Channel.

Comment: Yes, good point, I forgot to add that - you need of course to activate the Teams channel in the new bot. You'll also another separate app in Teams itself. You can copy the original manifest, update the  bot ID, and I'd suggest give it an adjusted name that reflects that it's "Dev"

Comment: By the way, if you feel the answer was correct, please "mark as answer"

Comment: great, glad to hear

Comment: Your bot also needs a public IP to connect to over https.   Microsoft recommends ngrok.  I've been using it for dev and it's been quite useful.